# Verilog can't output square wave if assigned to one variable but can to another

Tags: verilog, fpga

So I'm trying to output the bits of a variable in FPGA. There are two different variables: count and dataout. The code is as follows:

```
module control_LED
( //input [7:0] input_value,

  input Clk,

  //input reset,

  //output reg [7:0] dataout

  output led,led2,led3,led4,led5,led6,led7,led8
);
parameter DWIDTH = 8, WORDS = 30;

reg [27:0] count;

reg [7:0] dataout;

reg [DWIDTH-1:0]sine[WORDS-1:0];

//reg [7:0] temp;

initial begin

    count = 0;

    dataout = 0;

   sine[0] = 77;

   sine[1] = 74;

   sine[2] = 67;

   sine[3] = 58;

   sine[4] = 45;

   sine[5] = 31;

   sine[6] = 16;

   sine[7] = 0;

   sine[8] = 7;

   sine[9] = 8'd74;

   sine[10] = 8'd67;

   sine[11] = 8'd58;

   sine[12] = 8'd45;

   sine[13] = 8'd31;

   sine[14] = 8'd16;

   sine[15] = 8'd0;

   sine[16] = -16;

   sine[17] = -31;

   sine[18] = -45;

   sine[19] = -58;

   sine[20] = -67;

   sine[21] = -74;

   sine[22] = -77;

   sine[23] = -77;

   sine[24] = -74;

   sine[25] = -67;

   sine[26] = -58;

   sine[27] = -45;

   sine[28] = -31;

   sine[29] = -16;

end

always@ (posedge Clk)

begin

    if (count > 14) begin

      count<=0;

      dataout<=0;

     end

    else begin

     count<=count+1;

     //dataout<=dataout+1;

     dataout <=sine[count];

         //dataout <=sine[count];

     /*led <= sine[count][7];
     led2 <= sine[count][6];
     led3 <= sine[count][5];
     led4 <= sine[count][4];
     led5 <= sine[count][3];
     led6 <= sine[count][2];
     led7 <= sine[count][1];
     led8 <= sine[count][0];*/

    end

end

//assign dataout = sine[count];
/*assign led = count[7];
assign led2 = count[6];
assign led3 = count[5];
assign led4 = count[4];
assign led5 = count[3];
assign led6 = count[2];
assign led7 = count[1];
assign led8 = count[0];*/


assign led = dataout[7];

assign led2 = dataout[6];

assign led3 = dataout[5];

assign led4 = dataout[4];

assign led5 = dataout[3];

assign led6 = dataout[2];

assign led7 = dataout[1];

assign led8 = dataout[0];


endmodule
```

What happens is that if I assign the output variables to the bits in the count variable, the FPGA board output pins would give a clean square wave. But if I assign the output variable to the bits in the dataout variable, I don't. I don't know what is causing this.. I'm not looking for the direct answer but I have been struggling with this for a while now. So I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me a hint or push me in the direction. (I've been going round and round trying debug this). Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it supports initial blocks and yes, the variable should be signed.

Comment: There is a warning that says "Signal <sine> is used but never assigned". But it is assigned in the initial block...

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `dataout` bits are themselves not in square wave pattern due to your `sine` array values.

```
sine[0] = 77; // 01001101
sine[1] = 74; // 01001010
sine[2] = 67; // 01000011
sine[3] = 58; // 00111010
sine[4] = 45; // 00101101
sine[5] = 31; // 00011111
sine[6] = 16; // 00010000
sine[7] = 0;  // 00000000
sine[8] = 7;  // 00000111
sine[9] = 8'd74; // 01001010
sine[10] = 8'd67; // 01000011
sine[11] = 8'd58; // 00111010
sine[12] = 8'd45; // 00101101
sine[13] = 8'd31; // 00011111
sine[14] = 8'd16; // 00010000
sine[15] = 8'd0; // 0000000
```

Suppose you take `dataout[1]`, then with every clock it will have the following values.

```
0-1-1-1-0-1-0-0-1-1-1-1-0-1-0-0
```

So this itself is not repeatative in a particular interval.

Another important thing is that you dont have any `reset` in your design. So actually whatever you are doing in the `initial` block should be done in `reset` condition.

You can perform that with following code.

```
always @ (posedge clk, negedge reset)
begin
  if (!reset)
  begin
    // Your reset condition
  end
  else
  begin
    // Your original code
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, it's not repetitive. But I cannot detect a clear low/high levels on the oscilloscope. Instead, I can detect something close to a sine wave for each of the dataout bits.

Comment: I am not able to understand what do you see in the oscilloscope? I think you should first see it in the simulation to get the idea of your code and then dump it in FPGA. See my updated answer for another thing

Comment: um... it's like noise. If I increase the scale, it becomes something like a sine wave and a sinc wave added together. The problem is, my code works perfectly in simulation mode. But not when I dump it into the FPGA

Comment: If possible please post the oscilloscope screenshot

Comment: Please follow the link

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-sDXVEjomfZQ1ZHWGR6elg3Z0ZXQlQyd3N0SWpPVEpSWTVz

Comment: I think this is a noise only. Can you modify your code to drive continuous `1'b1` from that port, and see what oscilloscope shows?

Comment: The oscilloscope shows a constant high signal  as shown in the link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-sDXVEjomfZR054bmg5ZUo5dlU